# Restcomm cdr files

Tags: sip, voip, mobicents, restcomm

Having integrated our Billing system Meveo with RestComm to provision accounts and phone numbers, I would like to know where I can get CDR files and what is their format.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way it to fetch CDRs via the REST API. You can fetch records in a time frame (via list filter) and paginate to control overload of the Restcomm server:

Calls logs API:
http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-api-calls/

SMS message logs API:
http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-api-sms-messages/

Notice that some records returned by this API may be fore calls in-progress. To fetch only calls that completed or failed, use list filter parameters.

For very high load systems, it is better to read from the rolling CDR log files from a shared file system. We can discuss how this can be done in a separate thread.

Comment: Update. Work has begun on CDR files. https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/192